# How to get rid of cloning / duplication of elements in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, trello

I'm a beginner programmer and I create a spa like trello. Creates boards. In the board creates lists, they are displayed different with different id, but the list items are displayed with the same id and they are duplicated in each list. Sorry for my english:) Help me, please and tell in detail what the problem is.. Thank you very much

vuex file **router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    boards: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('boards') || '[]'),
    lists: [],
    items: []
    // items: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items') || '[]')
    // lists: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lists') || '[]')
  },
  mutations: {
    addBoard(state, board) {
      state.boards.push(board)
      localStorage.setItem('boards', JSON.stringify(state.boards))
    },
    addList(state, list) {
      state.lists.push(list)
      // localStorage.setItem('lists', JSON.stringify(state.lists))
    },
    createItemListt(state, item) {
      state.items.push(item)
      // localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(state.items))
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addBoard({commit}, board) {
      commit('addBoard', board)
    },
    addList({commit}, list) {
      commit('addList', list)
    },
    createItemListt({commit}, item) {
      commit('createItemListt', item)
    }
  },
  getters: {
    boards: s => s.boards,
    taskById: s => id => s.boards.find(t => t.id === id),
    lists: d => d.lists,
    items: a => a.items
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

the page on which the lists are created **MyBoard.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <h1>{{board.title}}</h1>
        <div class="list " v-for="list in lists" :key="list.idList">
          <div class="list__title">
            <h3>{{list.titleList}}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="list__card" v-for="item in items" :key="item.idItemList">
            <span class="list__item">{{item.itemList}}</span>
            <a class="btn-floating btn-tiny btn-check" tag="button">
              <i class="material-icons">check</i>
            </a>
          </div>
            <createItemList />
        </div>
         <createList />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    board() {
      return this.$store.getters.taskById(+this.$route.params.id);
    },
    lists() {
      return this.$store.getters.lists;
    },
    items() {
      return this.$store.getters.items;
    }
  },

  components: {
    createList: () => import("../components/createList"),
    createItemList: () => import("../components/createItemList")
  }
};
</script>
```

**CreateList.Vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="new-list" v-show="isCreating">
        <div class="list__title input-field">
          <input
            type="text"
            required
            id="list-title"
            class="none validate"
            tag="button"
            autofocus
            v-model="titleList"
            v-on:keyup.enter="createList"
          />
          <label for="list-title">Enter Title List</label>
        </div>

        <a class="btn-floating transparent btn-close" tag="button" @click="closeList">
          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="create-list z-depth-2" v-show="!isCreating">
        <p>Create list</p>
        <a
          class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light deep-purple lighten-2 pulse"
          tag="button"
          @click="addList"
          v-on:keyup.enter="addList"
        >
          <i class="material-icons">add</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    isCreating: false,
    titleList: "",
    idList: ""
  }),
  methods: {
    addList() {
      this.isCreating = true;
    },
    closeList() {
      this.isCreating = false;
    },
    createList() {
      if (this.titleList == "") {
        return false;
      }
      const list = {
        idList: Date.now(),
        titleList: this.titleList
      };
      this.$store.dispatch("addList", list);
      this.titleList =  "";
      this.isCreating = false;
      console.log(list.titleList);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**CreateItemList.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="add-item">
      <div class="textarea-item input-field" v-show="isAdding">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="validate"
          id="list-item"
          v-model="itemList"
          v-on:keyup.enter="createItemList"
          autofocus
        />
        <label for="list-item">Enter Item List</label>
      </div>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" v-show="!isAdding" @click="addCard">
        <i class="material-icons right">add</i>Add Card
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    isAdding: false,
    itemList: "",
  }),
  methods: {
    addCard() {
      this.isAdding = true;
    },
    createItemList() {
       if (this.itemList == "") {
        return false;
      }
      const item = {
        idItemList: Date.now(),
        itemList: this.itemList
      };

      this.$store.dispatch("createItemListt", item);
      this.itemList = "";
      this.isAdding = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[attach photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DhJm.png)

Comment: you have `items` and `lists` and `boards` - but I don't see how an `item` "knows" where it should belong (what `list` it's in), and `lists` don't seem to know about their `boards`. (And it's true in the other direction - the `boards` don't know what `lists` they have and the `lists` don't know what `items` they should contain. But I might have missed that logic.)

Comment: @muka.gergely, you are absolutely right..
If you create a new board, then all the lists are duplicated there ..
Tell me please how this can be fixed: so that the sheets understand which boards belong, etc.?

Comment: OK, then I prepare an answer to show you a solution to that (it may take some time, as it's a workday here)

Answer (score 1):

Tried to go with the basic idea of the structure you laid out. I added:

- `id` to all items, so they can be identifed
- `children` to appropriate items, so you can keep track of what's in them

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    tables: [
      { id: 1, children: ['1.1', '1.2'] },
      { id: 2, children: ['2.1'] }
    ],
    lists: [
      { id: '1.1', children: ['1.1.1'] },
      { id: '1.2', children: ['1.2.1'] },
      { id: '2.1', children: ['2.1.1', '2.1.2'] },
    ],
    cards: [
      { id: '1.1.1' },
      { id: '1.2.1' },
      { id: '2.1.1' },
      { id: '2.1.2' },
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_CARD(state, listId) {
      const list = state.lists.find(e => e.id === listId)
      const cards = state.cards
      const card = { id: Date.now() }
      cards.push( card )
      list.children.push( card.id )
    },
    ADD_LIST(state, tableId) {
      const table = state.tables.find(e => e.id === tableId)
      const lists = state.lists
      const list = { id: Date.now(), children: [] }
      lists.push( list )
      table.children.push( list.id )
    },
    ADD_TABLE(state) {
      const tables = state.tables
      const table = { id: Date.now(), children: [] }
      tables.push( table )
    },
    TRY_MOVING_LIST(state) {
      const table1 = state.tables.find(e => e.id === 1)
      const table2 = state.tables.find(e => e.id === 2)
      const item = table1.children.pop() // remove the last item
      table2.children.push(item)
      
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addCard({ commit }, listId) {
      commit('ADD_CARD', listId)
    },
    addList({ commit }, tableId) {
      commit('ADD_LIST', tableId)
    },
    addTable({ commit }) {
      commit('ADD_TABLE')
    },
    tryMovingList({ commit }) {
      commit('TRY_MOVING_LIST')
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getTables: s => s.tables,
    getListById: s => id => s.lists.find(e => e.id === id),
    getCardById: s => id => s.cards.find(e => e.id === id),
  }
})

Vue.component('CustomCard', {
  props: ['card'],
  template: `<div>
    card ID: {{ card.id }}<br />
  </div>`
})

Vue.component('CustomList', {
  props: ['list'],
  template: `<div>
    list ID: {{ list.id }}<br />
    <custom-card
      v-for="item in list.children"
      :key="item"
      :card="getCard(item)"
    />
    <button @click="addCard">ADD CARD +</button>
    <hr />
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    getCard(id) {
      return this.$store.getters.getCardById(id)
    },
    addCard() {
      this.$store.dispatch('addCard', this.list.id)
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('CustomTable', {
  props: ['cTable'],
  template: `<div>
    table ID: {{ cTable.id }}<br />
    <custom-list
      v-for="item in cTable.children"
      :key="item"
      :list="getList(item)"
    />
    <button @click="addList">ADD LIST +</button>
    <hr />
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    getList(id) {
      return this.$store.getters.getListById(id)
    },
    addList(id) {
      this.$store.dispatch('addList', this.cTable.id)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  computed: {
    tables() {
      return this.$store.state.tables
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTable() {
      this.$store.dispatch('addTable')
    },
    tryMovingList() {
      // this function will move the last list in table ID 1
      // to the end of table ID 2's lists
      // NOT FOOLPROOF - you should add error handling logic!
      this.$store.dispatch('tryMovingList')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="tryMovingList()">MOVE LIST</button><br />
  <button @click="addTable()">ADD TABLE +</button>
  <hr />
  <custom-table v-for="item in tables" :key="'table-' + item.id" :c-table="item" />
</div>
```

With this setup you can change the hierarchy quite easily: just delete an ID from one `Array` of children and add it to another (e.g. remove `'1.1'` from `table` ID 1's `children` array and add it to `table` ID 2's `children` array - everything moved to `table` ID 2. `tryMovingList()` does exactly this - this method/action is **not foolproof**, just for you to try out moving a whole list)

There could be other patterns to solve this problem (like a real **linked list** data structure or the **mediator** pattern), but for smaller apps this is OK, I think (I would use it... :) ).

### ONE PIECE OF ADVICE

If you want to store state in `localStorage` on mutations, don't do it by yourself - use **Vuex**'s integrated `subscribe` mechanism: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe

Comment: thank you so much you..I want to become a professional like you, thank you again

Comment: @sergius Thank you very much for the compliment! :) But believe me - time will bring the experience (and then you'll see that there are always people with much more knowledge than you, so the learning never stops :D ) Anyways, I'm happy that I could help!

Comment: help me more time, please. Different sheets are displayed in different tables, but the renderer swears at the cards, it displays the error "Error in render:" TypeError: _vm.list is undefined ""

Although in vuex when accessed via console.log (list.children), all children of the list are displayed. Can we contact via skype or any messenger?

Comment: @sergius migh be a problem with the order these items are initiated. Please create a JSFiddle (or something like that) with the code you did.

Comment: https://github.com/audito/copyTrello

is it convenient there?

Error in component "CreateList"

Comment: replace please
to
`
      <div class="list" v-for="(item, id) in cards" :key="id" :card="getCard(id)">
        <!-- <createItemList /> -->
        <span>{{item.itemList}}</span>
      </div>
`

Comment: if you replace "cards" with "list.children" on line 12, an error will occur

Comment: https://github.com/gegeke/copyTrello/blob/dev/src/components/createList.vue - the bug named is solved there (no error message comes up), but the problems are a bit deeper than you think. Sorry to say, but the component-structure is a bit confusing - it'll be hard to work with. (I tried to go forward some steps, but it would've taken too much time to rebuild the structure, sorry.) I suggest you to think over what should be a component in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your time, how I find a solution - I will write to you